# How can I make sure the compiler parallelizes my loads from global memory?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I've written a CUDA kernel that looks something like this:

```
int tIdx = threadIdx.x; // Assume a 1-D thread block and a 1-D grid
int buffNo = 0;
for (int offset=buffSz*blockIdx.x; offset<totalCount; offset+=buffSz*gridDim.x) {
    // Select which "page" we're using on this iteration
    float *buff = &sharedMem[buffNo*buffSz];
    // Load data from global memory
    if (tIdx < nLoadThreads) {
        for (int ii=tIdx; ii<buffSz; ii+=nLoadThreads)
            buff[ii] = globalMem[ii+offset];
    }
    // Wait for shared memory
    __syncthreads();
    // Perform computation
    if (tIdx >= nLoadThreads) {
        // Perform some computation on the contents of buff[]
    }
    // Switch pages
    buffNo ^= 0x01;
}
```

Note that there's only one `__syncthreads()` in the loop, so the first `nLoadThreads` threads will start loading the data for the 2nd iteration while the rest of the threads are still computing the results for the 1st iteration.

I was thinking about how many threads to allocate for loading vs. computing, and I reasoned that I would only need a single warp for loading, regardless of buffer size, because that inner for loop consists of independent loads from global memory: they can all be in flight at the same time. Is this a valid line of reasoning?

And yet when I try this out, I find that (1) increasing the # of load warps dramatically increases performance, and (2) the disassembly in `nvvp` shows that `buff[ii] = globalMem[ii+offset]` was compiled into a load from global memory followed 2 instructions later by a store to shared memory, indicating that the compiler is not applying instruction-level parallelism here.

Would additional qualifiers (`const`, `__restrict__`, etc) on `buff` or `globalMem` help ensure the compiler does what I want?

I suspect the problem has to do with the fact that `buffSz` is not known at compile-time (the actual data is 2-D and the appropriate buffer size depends on the matrix dimensions). In order to do what I want, the compiler will need to allocate a separate register for each LD operation in flight, right? If I manually unroll the loop, the compiler re-orders the instructions so that there are a few LD in flight before the corresponding ST needs to access that register. I tried a `#pragma unroll` but the compiler only unrolled the loop without reordering the instructions, so that didn't help. What else can I do?

Comment: Is this a *gendankenexperiment*, or are you trying to solve an actual problem with actual code here? It isn't obvious from your question whether the compiler behaviour you seem concerned is actually happening, or whether this is just an exercise in thinking aloud.

Comment: Sorry, I can see how it could have been confusing, and I've edited the question to clarify. This is an actual problem, that is a simplified code snippet, and this is a real compiler behavior. I would love to have a answer to this problem, even if that answer is "No, the optimization you're describing is too hard for the compiler toolchain".

Comment: I think it is going to be very hard to give you an answer without real code to  analyze. My first reaction is would be to try looking at templating the loop trips. If you only have a finite number of different buffer sizes, then it wouldn't be too arduous to instantiate them all. Then the compiler can potentially unroll loops. But it is very hard to say without something more concrete to look at.

Comment: Why would you want to use fewer threads for loading than available?

Comment: @tera: At some point increasing the # of load threads per block limits the # of blocks per MP. For some problem sizes this happens immediately. Which led me to question, "why would you want to use more threads for loading when a single thread (with unrolled load loop) can have multiple LD in flight at the same time?"

Comment: You don't need to use separate load threads. As all threads of the block are waiting at the `__syncthreads()` anyway you can use the same threads for loading and computation.

Comment: Since there isn't a second `__syncthreads()` at the end of the loop, the threads not involved in computation (`tIdx<nLoadThreads`) will go on to load data for the next loop iteration. I'm hoping the computation will mask the load latency, but that doesn't work if the load threads incur the load latency `buffSz/nLoadThreads` times.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to use a producer/consumer model as described in the [PTX ISA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#parallel-synchronization-and-communication-instructions-bar). This requires use of inline "assembly" but would be most effective in decoupling the two kinds of threads.

Comment: [I am too slow - above comment typed before seeing your previous one].

Comment: How many bytes/floats to you want to load per iteration and how many computation threads are there in a block?

Comment: The size of the problem varies with the dimension of the input data. The problematic case arises when there's 640 computation threads/block, and 3 KB to load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122852/discussion-between-kqs-and-tera).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler has no chance to reorder stores to shared memory away from loads from global memory, because a `__syncthreads()` barrier is immediately following.
As all off the threads have to wait at the barrier anyway, it is faster to use more threads for loading. This means that more global memory transactions can be in flight at any time, and each load thread has to incur global memory latency less often.

All CUDA devices so far do not support out-of-order execution, so the load loop will incur exactly one global memory latency per loop iteration, unless the compiler can unroll it and reorder loads before stores.

To allow full unrolling, the number of loop iterations needs to be known at compile time. You can use talonmies' suggestion of templating the loop trips to achieve this.

You can also use partial unrolling. Annotating the load loop with `#pragma unroll 2` will allow the compiler to issue two loads, then two stores for every two loop iterations, thus achieve a similar effect to doubling `nLoadThreads`. Replacing `2` with higher numbers is possible, but you will hit the maximum number of transactions in flight at some point (use float2 or float4 moves to transfer more data with the same number of transactions). Also it is difficult to predict whether the compiler will prefer reordering instructions over the cost of more complex code for the final, potentially partial, trip through the unrolled loop.

So the **suggestions** are:

1. Use as many load threads as possible.
2. Unroll the load loop by templating the number of loop iterations and instantiating it for all possible number of loop trips (or the most common ones, with a generic fallback), or by using partial loop unrolling.
3. If the data is suitably aligned, move it as `float2` or `float4` to move more data with the same number of transactions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! (0) I tried the `#pragma unroll` and found that the compiler did not choose to reorder the instructions. (1) In some cases "as many as possible" = 1 warp; adding more warps reduces the # of blocks/MP. (2) Templating the trip counts is an interesting trick! I will see if this produces reordered instructions. (3) `float4` is a great idea! I had no idea these existed (I'm a total newcomer to CUDA) and I think it'll help a lot. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: The combo of `float4` and templating the loop count (so that the load loop trip count is known at compile-time) was a winner. The compiler didn't reorder *all* of the LD/ST, but having four 128-bit loads in flight (per thread) was enough that the computations could hide the memory latency.